# How to make a function inherit the return type of the returned function?

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I have a function that takes in a function and return the result of `useSelector` hook from `react-redux`.

How can i use the return type of `useSelector` in my wrapper function ?

```
import { shallowEqual, useSelector } from 'react-redux';

type SelectorFunction = (state: AppState) => /* TypeOfReturn */;

export default (selector: SelectorFunction) => useSelector(selector, shallowEqual);
```

Right now my function returns `any`, i want to avoid doing things like this

```
const user = useShallowEqualSelector(state => state.userAuth.user) as User | null;
```

If i use `useSelector` only the type of `user` is indeed `User | null`

```
const user = useSelector((state: AppState) => state.userAuth.user);
```

Comment: `export default <TS,TR>(selector: (s:TS)=>TR) => useSelector<TS,TR>(selector,shallowEqual)` should work. based off the type in @types/react-redux

Comment: @Badashi Thank you, It works  like this `export default <TR>(selector: (state: AppState) => TR) => useSelector<AppState, TR>(selector, shallowEqual);
` mind giving an explanation in an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, the idea here is to have a fixed state type(`AppState`) but the return type of the selector function varies according to the selector function itself -- passed as a parameter

In that case, you can use a parametrized type:

```
export default <TReturn>(selector: (state: AppState) => TReturn) => useSelector<AppState, TReturn>(selector, shallowEqual)
```

with this, typescript can infer the return type for `useSelector` automatically, based off what you pass as the `selector` function-parameter. This is different from "using the return type of useSelector" because `useSelector` itself has a parametized return type, instead we're just deferring the return type to the higher order function.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, last question how can i split the function into a declaration and an implementation ?